# Laravel General error: 1005 Can't create table `categories_products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Trying to migrate in laravel and this error poped up. I thought error could be bigInteger type as i found in another same question answer. Refer to change bigInteger to bigIncrements, but nothing i got another error about type constraint.

**Code**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**Error**

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `categories_products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `categori
  es_products` add constraint `categories_products_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `categories_products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `categories_products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are sure the categories table already exists and there is no typo in the table name?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnICU . I made Exactly same mistake as Kaan specified in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give a definate answer without seeing the column definition on the target table for the relation. The types need to match. So if you are using a bigIncrements() for the id field then `unsignedBigInteger()` or `bigInteger()->unsigned()` should both work as the type of the foreign key, however if you are using `increments` for the id then the foreign key needs to be an `unsignedInteger()` or `integer()->unsigned()`

Comment: Thank you so much @Kaan. Exactly same mistake i was making. In product table i m using bigIncrements so its ok. Mistake was in category i m using increments.